# WebSocket connector for Apache Beam (Java)?

Tags: java, websocket, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have an Apache Beam pipeline wrote in Java where I would like to read data that comes from a Websocket.

I have been looking for some connectors but so far my search was unsuccessful.